# Opening mailto: links from webview

Tags: android-webview, ibm-mobilefirst

Just want to start off by saying I'm not a much of a Java dev or anything of an Android dev. The links I've found on SO for solving my issue aren't specific to WL, and I'm not sure where to place the 'solutions' in the build.

I've got simple email link to start this:

```
<a href="mailto:foo@bar.com"></a>
```

In Android (4.0.4) the app will crash saying it's not a supported protocol. That much is expected.

One of the solutions I have (below, from SO, lost the link) seems like the right way to go, but I'm not sure where this is supposed to go.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebViewClient view, String url) {
    if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Otherwise allow the OS to handle it
    else if (url.startsWith("tel:")) { 
        Intent tel = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)); 
        startActivity(tel);
        return true;
    }
    else if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
        String body = "Enter your Question, Enquiry or Feedback below:\n\n";
        Intent mail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        mail.setType("application/octet-stream");
        mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"email address"});
        mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
        mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
        startActivity(mail);
        return true;
        }
    return true;
}
```

Any help is obviously greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Worklight hybrid application, you are not required to use native code in order to use features such as `mailto:`.

To get it working, i.e: to click a link that will open the email screen for the user to fill in the subject and message, you can follow the below. If you need greater functionality, elaborate on it in your question:

1. Make sure you are using the latest iFix available for the version of Worklight that you are using ([due to recently fixed Cordova security bugs that affect this functionality](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/action_required_cordova_android_security_update?lang=en)). This can be obtained from either the Eclipse Marketplace or IBM Fix Central.
2. Follow these steps:

   - In native\res\xml\config.xml, remove and add the following lines:

     ```
     - <access origin="*"/>
     + <access origin="mailto://*" launch-external="true" />
     ```
   - In common\index.html I then tried with:

     ```
     <a href="mailto:my@email.address?Subject=Hello%20again">Send email</a>
     ```

The result was (depending on your phone setup): either to get an option to set up an email account, select from which account to send the mail to, or get the email compose screen.

Comment: The config.xml is what did it. I didn't know what I had to change to allow mailto: to be handled, and all my googling only turned up non-worklight answers, hence the java override in my question. Thanks for the quick solution.